# Gridview - check nested gridview rows

Tags: c#, gridview

I have two gridviews: parent and child. My goal is to update parent table with values from child table (this will be done in database). To complete this I need to read values from child gridview. I created below code but child rows are not read properly (I am gettin index is out of range error):

```
    protected void btnUpdateSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row_master in gvParent.Rows)
            {
                if (row_master.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    GridView gvChild = (GridView)gvParent.Rows[row_master.RowIndex].FindControl("gvChild");

                    if (gvChild != null)
                    {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row_child in gvChild.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row_child.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            CheckBox chckboxChild = (CheckBox)row_child.FindControl("chckboxChild");

                            if (chckboxChild.Checked == true & gvChild.Rows.Count == 1)
                            {
                                int index_master = Convert.ToInt32(row_master.RowIndex.ToString());
                                int index_child = Convert.ToInt32(row_child.RowIndex.ToString());

                                int rowID_a = Convert.ToInt32(gvParent.DataKeys[index_master].Values["ID"]);
                                int rowID_b = Convert.ToInt32(gvChild.DataKeys[index_master].Values["ID"]);
                                int serverID = Convert.ToInt32(gvParent.DataKeys[index_master].Values["ServerID"]);
                                int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvChild.DataKeys[index_child].Values["DeviceID"]);
                                int activeStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(gvChild.DataKeys[index_child].Values["ActiveStatusID"]);
                                string managedBy = gvChild.DataKeys[index_child].Values["ManagedBy"].ToString();
                                string monitoredBy = gvChild.DataKeys[index_child].Values["MonitoredBy"].ToString();
                                int managementProtocolID = Convert.ToInt32(gvChild.DataKeys[index_child].Values["ManagementProtocolID"]);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side-note: the `DataControlRowType` check is redundant when you use `foreach` since you only enumerate `DataRow`s.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so you are saying that I should remove foreach (GridViewRow row_child in gvChild.Rows)? I just copied this part of code form another method where I am checking all rows.

Comment: Not the foreach but the type check.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I removed DataControlRowType check but it still doesn't work. I am receiving "Index was out of range" for child row. Please advise.

Comment: I found where the problem was. In one of the records I put index_master instead of index_child.

Comment: You can answer your own question and show the code that fixed the problem. Maybe it could help somebody else in future.